# How to send data from c++ to java - android

Tags: java, android, c++, native

I want to transfer buffer array from a c++ library to the java file. My java file is located inside frameworks/base/core/java (It's not an android application). The C++ will be in the form of an executable after compilation.

I've figured how would I load the library in my java file and call it's methods but I'm not getting how to send the buffer array from c++ to my java file.

I'm open to any discussion if it is even possible or not.

Edit: The executable after compilation will be located inside /system/bin/

Answer (score 0):

JNI can also be used to invoke Java code from within natively-written applications - such as those written in C/C++.

In fact, the java command-line utility is an example of one such application, that launches Java code in a Java Virtual Machine.

[Visit this link](https://thenewcircle.com/bookshelf/java_fundamentals_tutorial/_java_native_interface_jni.html)

Comment: I already told it's not an android application. I'm compiling the whole android. and after compilation my executable will be located at `/system/bin/`.

I want something like I'll execute that binary from my java and receive the buffer array.

Comment: I haven't wrote anything yet. I'm not getting the idea of how will I transfer an array from the binary to my java file. Right now the only idea in my mind is to call `Runtime.exec("mybinary")` from java file and somehow receive the array. The other idea could be `System.loadLibrary("mybinary")` and call it's method. But atlast I'm still stuck on how would I transfer the array (array won't be in readable format).

Comment: Can you please edit your answer on how to achieve it in c++. I'm new to c++. Java part I'll handle.

Comment: Visit above Answer link ,It will be very useful to you

Comment: ohkey but even in this I will need to use sockets ? I know about using JNI framework but nothing about sockets in c++.

Comment: go through this website for C++ socket programmers   www.codeproject.com/Articles/13071/Programming-Windows-TCP-Sockets-in-C-for-the-Begin